# How to programatically change BindingSource for DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview, bindingsource

My question arises from my main objective which is to create ONE GENERIC SIMPLE form with DataGridView and BindingNavigator. I named this form "DataGridForm".

How do I change the BindingSource via codebehind?

I found this option on DataGridView in designer but i want to switch it programatically. My main goal is to have one Form which can show different tables depending on the parameters passed via constructor (source, dataMember).

[image]

When I chose table called "Artikl" the "artiklBindingSource" and "artiklTableAdapters" were automatically generated...

I'm confused... why couldn't I just pass dataTable as DataSource and say "Artikl" as DataMember (I always got message datamember couldn't be found in datasource)... what is the need of stronlgy typed TableAdapter?

```
        public DataGridForm(DataTable source, string dataMember) // CONSTRUCTOR
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // TODO: Complete member initialization
            //this.enumerable = enumerable;

            this.bindingSource.DataSource = source;
            //this.dataGridView.DataMember = dataMember;
        }

        private void DataGridForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) // GENERATED CODE
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'kasaMPDataSet.Artikl' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.artiklTableAdapter.Fill(this.kasaMPDataSet.Artikl);

        }
```

What is the correct approach to this problem?

Comment: Instead of using binding source I just use DataSource : datagridview1.DataSource = dt;

Comment: I did that if you look at my constructor, but I have BindingNavigator which needs BindingSource

Comment: Move the binding source from the constructor to the load method.  The DGV isn't fully built in the constructor so you need to add the code in the load instead.

Comment: Still haven't answered my original problem "My main goal is to have one Form which can show different tables depending on the parameters passed via constructor (source, dataMember)."

Comment: The add another method that does binding which has the source as a parameter.  You can't do the binding in the constructor.

Comment: OK I'll try, thanks for input